# Correlation and p-value of raster

Tags: r, r-raster, p-value, pearson-correlation

I have 4 rasters and I calculated the correlation matrix with this code; 
but I need to know the p-value and I haven't been able to do it. Can you help me?

```r
a<-stack(FS2,FP2,W2,P)

jnk=layerStats(a, 'pearson', na.rm=T)
corr_matrix=jnk$'pearson correlation coefficient'
```

Comment: Please make this a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What is `FS2`? `FP2`?

Comment: the name of the raster, Fs = Fire scar, Fp = Fire points, W = water level, and P = peat depth.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the corLocal function in the raster package:

```
library(raster)
b <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
b <- aggregate(b, 2, mean)

#flip one layer so values differ:
set.seed(0)
b[[2]] <- flip(b[[2]], 'y') + runif(ncell(b))
b[[1]] <- b[[1]] + runif(ncell(b))
plot(b)

#run correlation
x <- corLocal(b[[1]], b[[2]], test=TRUE )

#view pearson correlation and p-value
plot(x)
```